# Python newb "Fill in the empty function so that it returns the sum of all the divisors of a number, without including it."

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good Day I'm a Python newb and I'm having a hard time figuring out how'd the output ended up 55? Also what is this sum in return sum?
Are there any other methods also to make it less complicated?

```
def sum_divisors(n):
 return sum([i for i in range(1, n) if n % i == 0])

print(sum_divisors(36))

output:
55
```

Comment: Try to remove `sum` in the function, inspect the returned list. Does it make sense now? ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok the output is 55 because ur summing up all divisors of `36`
which are

```
1
2
3
4
6
9
12
18
```

let n = 36

ur iterating over the range and checking if the number when divided with `n` returns 0 as remainder

as for making it look simpler, look at this

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum_list = []
    for num in range(1, n):
        if n%num == 0:
           sum_list.append(num)
           
    return sum(sum_list)
```

Comment: I really understand it now, thanks for the help.